# Validate slug with Regexp with slash allowed

Tags: javascript, regex

I use regexp to validate a slug.

`const rule = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$')`

It works well though, I would like to `/` have them accepted

Example: `my-parent-page/my-child-page`

With my original Regex, this slug is invalidated while it should be correct

Thank you

Comment: You're asking us to write code for you, which is off-topic. Instead, show us the smallest *runnable* code that demonstrates the problem and the error, and we'll help fix the error. [mre] will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a slash to the delimiting expression `[-/]`, so the alphanumeric part can be joined by either...

```js
const re = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9]+([-/][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$');

const egs = [
  'justSlash/justSlash',
  'just-dash',
  'dash-and-slash/dash-and-slash',
  '&crap'
];

egs.forEach(eg => console.log(re.test(eg) ? "match" : "no match") )
```